# How to manipulate data from binance stream

Tags: python

I am trying to manipulate the following data from a websocket.

Here is the data:

{'e': 'kline', 'E': 1659440374345, 's': 'MATICUSDT', 'k': {'t': 1659440100000, 'T': 1659440399999, 's': 'MATICUSDT', 'i': '5m', 'f': 274454614, 'L': 274455188, 'o': '0.87210000', 'c': '0.87240000', 'h': '0.87240000', 'l': '0.87000000', 'v': '145806.50000000', 'n': 575, 'x': False, 'q': '127036.96453000', 'V': '76167.60000000', 'Q': '66365.16664000', 'B': '0'}}

I am trying to extract following: 'E', 's' AND 'c'. To manipulate to: 'E' = time, 's' = symbol and 'c' = PRICE

```
def createframe(msg):
    df = pd.DataFrame([msg])
    df = df.loc[:,['s','E','c']
    df.columns = ['symbol', 'Time', 'Price']
    df.Price = df.Price.astype(float)
    df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, unit = 'ms')
    return df
```

When I run the next line of code to pull data:

```
async with stream as receiver:
    while True:
        data = await receiver.recv()
        data = json.loads(data)['data']
        df = createframe(data)
        print(df)
```

I am getting error that 'c' is not defined.

PLEASE HELP. THANK YOU

Comment: Just guessing, you may not have initialized the data frame properly, with column names. See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).
EDIT: Ah, perhaps you need to set the columns before using loc. I'd then rename and drop columns with other DataFrame methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the data frame, you'll see that in column "k" you have a whole dictionary's worth of data. That's because the value of k is itself a dictionary. You're getting the error that c is not defined because it is not a column itself, just a piece of data in column "k".

In order to get all this data into individual columns, you'll have to "flatten" the data. You can do something like this:

```
def createframe(msg):
    df = pd.DataFrame([msg])
    df = df.loc[:,['s','E','c']]
    df.columns = ['symbol', 'Time', 'Price']
    df.Price = df.Price.astype(float)
    df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, unit = 'ms')
    return df

def flatten(data):
    newdict = {}
    for each in msg:
        if isinstance(msg[each], dict):
            for i in msg[each]:
                newdict[i] = msg[each][i]
        else:
            newdict[each] = msg[each]
    return newdict

async with stream as receiver:
    while True:
        data = await receiver.recv()
        data = json.loads(data)['data']
        data = flatten(data)
        df = createframe(data)
        print(df)
```

Hope this helps! If you have questions just comment on this answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, where would I implement the above to 'flatten' the data. I now understand the dictionary within 'k'. Still struggling. Thanks (new to this)

Comment: No worries at all! I was going to explain in this comment, but I'll edit my answer to include a modified version of your code. This "flattening" will happen before you turn the data into a dataframe!

Comment: Unfortunately, still giving me the same error...

Comment: Oops, as I ran this code I also noticed you're missing a square bracket at the end of your     df = df.loc[:,['s','E','c'] statement. Updating my answer as well-- looks like I'm a little new to this as well ;).

Comment: I have amended the question, as you will see, the error is coming from next line of code when I try pull the data. error - "c is not in index'. Any ideas? Your help has been and is greatly appreciated!

Comment: No problem :)! Okay, so I see that you're running this loop without "flattening the data", I'm now going to edit -my- answer; copy and paste it into your code and see if it helps!!

Comment: I'm so glad it worked! Would you mind upvoting and confirming my answer? It helps me answer other people's questions too!